# How to trim() data of a modelless form before validate in Cakephp 4

Tags: trim, cakephp-4.x

In cakephp 4, in the case of a form with Model Table I use the callback method `ModelTable::beforeMarshal()` to `trim()` data before validation, but where can I do that in the case of a Modelless Form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no events/callbacks for it, there's only `Form.buildValidator`, but this only applies when validation is actually happening, and on top of that, only when the `buildValidator()` method has been implemented.

If you want to do it generally, and *before* validation, then you could for example override `\Cake\Form\Form::execute()`:

```php
public function execute(array $data, array $options = []): bool
{
    // modify $data here

    return parent::execute($data, $options);
}
```